# @client.command(), what arguments does it take in?

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a help command, and instead of adding each command description, name, aliases etc seperately, I made a for loop to go through all of the client.commands. But I only want to show the commands that have the type="misc" in command.type. Usage, description, aliases, and name work fine, but type doesnt
for example:
ping command -

```
@client.command(name="ping", description="Check the bot latency.", usage='`stonk ping`', type= "misc")
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
async def ping(ctx):
  random = discord.Color.random()
  ping = Embed(title="Pong!", description = f"My ping is **{round(client.latency * 1000)}ms**", color=random)
  ping.set_footer(text=ctx.guild.name, icon_url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
  await ctx.reply(embed=ping)
```

Help command that goes through each command.

```
em = Embed(title="Stonker Command List", description="This embed was sponsored by: **Stonk Man**", color=random)
em.set_footer(text="Stonkman Smort Inveshtor, Be Like Stonkman")
for c in client.commands:
    if c.type == "misc":
        em.add_field(name=f"{c.name}", value=f"**Aliases**: {', '.join(c.aliases)}\n**Description**: {c.description}\n**Usage**: {c.usage}", inline=False)
```

But when i run it, it says command has no attribute "type". so I want to know what variable thingies can you put into @client.command( here )
sorry if this is confusing i dont know how to explain

Comment: Heres a really good help command walkthrough: https://gist.github.com/InterStella0/b78488fb28cadf279dfd3164b9f0cf96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Bot.command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command) decorator simply passes the keyword arguments over to the [`commands.Command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command) constructor. The documentation does not clearly specify which attributes can be passed as keyword arguments, but in the [source code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/bac6c2fc7b5c12c8da260578302d45e8ee2e5417/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L255) I could find the following attributes:

- `name`
- `enabled`
- `help`
- `brief`
- `usage`
- `rest_is_raw`
- `aliases`
- `extras`
- `hidden`
- `checks`
- `cooldown`
- `max_concurrency`
- `require_var_positional`
- `ignore_extra`
- `cooldown_after_parsing`
- `parent`

See the [`commands.Command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command) documentation for more info about each of these attributes. Note that `type` is not a valid keyword argument, so it will be ignored.